# Repeat complex change to text in vim

Tags: vim

In the following code snippet, I want to typecast each of `total`, `MB` and `free` into `float()`

```
totalMBytes = int32(total / MB)
freeMBytes = int32(free / MB)
```

Is there a quick way to make this change just at one location and use a trick in vim to apply it elsewhere? The expected output is:

```
totalMBytes = int32(float(total) / float(MB))
freeMBytes = int32(float(free) / float(MB))
```

Comment: You can use macros to do that. By the way, can you give an example of expected output?

Comment: You could use a global search and replace with confirmation `%s/\v(total|free|MB)/float()/gc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, we have a [vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/) part of the website specialised in Vim questions.  It is likely that you will get better answers there (if you have more Vim questions).

---

Yet, on the question itself, there are several ways of doing it.  Starting from:

```
[t]otalMBytes = int32(total / MB)
freeMBytes = int32(free / MB)
```

Assuming the cursor at the `t` (as marked) and assuming that the file has other lines.  And that the final result shall be:

```
totalMBytes = (float)int32((float)total / (float)MB)
freeMBytes = (float)int32((float)free / (float)MB)
```

Let us give several options:

#### Use `.`

Use `w` to jump words and `.` to repeat changes, as follows:

```
2wi(float)<esc>3w.3w.5w.3w.3w.
```

Explanation:

- `2w` jumps 2 words forward.
- `i(float)<esc>` enter insert mode, insert (float) and exit insert mode.
- `3w` move 3 words forward
- `.` repeat last change in this position
- ... rinse repeat

(you can just move around and use `.`, you do not need to go word by word).

#### Use a regex

Select both lines with `Vj` and

```
:'<,'>s/\v([ (])(\w)/\1(float)\2/g
```

#### Use a macro

Press `qq` to record a macro in register `q` and do:

```
2wi(float)<esc>3w.3w.
```

This is the same as in the first example, but preforms the change for the first line only.  Now press `q` to stop recording the macro, and `jg^` to get to the first character of the next line.  Finally execute the macro:

```
@q
```

Comment: Great answer. Much appreciated.